# Using a Code Repositories library in a Code Workbook

Tags: shared-libraries, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks

Is it possible to build a library using Code Repositories and then call that library in a Code Workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to ensure that the shared channel that libraries are published to from Code Repositories is configured in the Code Workbook profile's `conda-environment.shared-channel-dependencies` setting.

Please work with your Palantir Support Team to get this backend configuration change made.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do it for testing purposes.

**Create the library**

1. Create the repository of *Python Library* type:

   [image]
2. Add the function:

   [image]
3. You can inspect the library name in the file *gradle.properties*.
   ***Note:** underscores **`_`** will be translated into hyphens **`-`***

   [image]
4. *Commit* and pull into the master branch.
5. Create a new tag (necessary) and wait until *Checks* pass.

   [image]

   [image]

**Create Code Workbook**

1. Create a new code workbook in the same project:

   [image]
2. "Environment" -> "Customize Spark environment".

   [image]
3. Click "Customize profile".
4. Search for and add your library:

   [image]
5. Click "Update environment" and wait until the customized environment initializes.

**Result**

[image]